# Select data from existing file

Tags: python

I have a Tab delimited file that has data in the following order (about 2400 rows)-

```
| SNO | Model#|Agent Name  | cost | MRP |    date    | Discount |
|---------------------------------------------------------------|
|   1 | 1112B | Chris      |  689 | 998 | 01/01/2014 | 5%       |
```

I want to

(1) Take out the Name and corresponding MRP and store it into a new file

expected outcome should be the following (stored in a new excel file or tab delimited text file)

```
| AgentName | MRP  |
|-----------|------|
| Chris     |  988 |
| A         |  111 |
| B         | 222  |
| C         |  333 |
| D         |  444 |
```

I started doing the following but could not finalize -

```
with open ('/path.txt') as f:
    for l in f:
        print l.strip().split("\t")
```

Comment: What type of file do you have in use currently? `.csv`? `.txt`?

Comment: We don't do homework here.

Comment: @DirtyBit - i have tab delimited file.(.txt)

Answer (score 1):

If the file is available in csv format, then you can do it with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = read_csv('/path to file.csv', sep='\t')
slice = df[['AgentName','MRP']] 
slice.to_csv('new_file.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks amanb, here is the error - ImportError: No module named pandas. I have Python 2.7 (on OSX)

Comment: Use `pip install pandas` to install it.

Comment: @HashCode Pandas has the benefit of you being able to visualize the new table before exporting it. you could do `print(slice)` before doing `slice.to_csv()` and it will show a table of sorts in your console/IDE

Comment: Yes, that is correct. There are many other features in pandas, that you can make use of depending upon your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Using only standard library [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader):

```
import csv
with open ('Project1.txt', 'rU') as from_fp, open('output.tsv', 'w') as to_fp:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(from_fp, dialect=csv.excel_tab)
    csv_writer = csv.writer(to_fp, delimiter='\t')
    csv_writer.writerow(['AgentName', 'MRP'])
    for row in csv_reader:
        csv_writer.writerow([row.get('AgentName'), row.get('MRP')])
```

Link to [demo](https://repl.it/@krasu/SO55606081)

Comment: Thanks krasu, this is helpful. I ran the code and got the following output..... an output txt file (tab delimited) with header AgentName and MRP. The values (rows) were missing.

Comment: I see the following - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "readfile.py", line 9, in <module>
    for row in csv_reader:
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/csv.py", line 107, in next
    self.fieldnames
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/csv.py", line 90, in fieldnames
    self._fieldnames = self.reader.next()
_csv.Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?

Comment: @cyberbabble could you please update your question with a content from an actual file, a first few lines will be more than enough?

Comment: @cyberbabble also you could try to add following change to the code above and see if it will work for you: `with open ('/path.txt', 'rU') as from_fp, open('/new_path.tsv', 'w') as to_fp:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(from_fp, dialect=csv.excel_tab)`

Comment: added the data file with my question. Here are the updates you suggested that i ran -   import csv

with open ('/inputfilepath.txt', 'rU') as from_fp, open('/outputfilepath.txt', 'w') as to_fp: 
 csv_reader = csv.DictReader(from_fp, dialect=csv.excel_tab)
    csv_writer = csv.writer(to_fp, delimiter='\t')
    csv_writer.writerow(['AgentName', 'MRP'])
 for row in csv_reader:
     csv_writer.writerow([row.get('AgentName'), row.get('MRP')])

Comment: received the following Error - 
  File "Readfile_v3.py", line 8
    csv_writer = csv.writer(to_fp, delimiter='\t')
                                                                     ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: @HashCode I've updated answer to mach your file and added a demo for you https://repl.it/@krasu/SO55606081

Comment: @Krasu- Thank you. it worked. Appreciate your help!